# How do I compile an IDL file for CORBA?

Tags: java, corba

i have a problem here where i have to compile an IDL file to be used in java. actually i want to use OTS or JTS for this and all i foun dout is that the IDL file needs to import another file and so on, here is the code:

```
#include "C:\java\jts1_0\CosTransactions.idl"

interface ITransaction: CosTransactions::TransactionalObject
{
    double charge( in double arg0 );
};
```

and i thought, let's compile with: idlj -fall ITransaction
with the following result:

```
ITransaction.idl (line 9): There is a forward reference to CosTransactions/Current, but it is not defined.
```

i read that i have to do this in a large tutorial and now i have no idea what could be wrong. ok current is not defined, well why?! jts is supposed to work, right?!

...

Comment: Please, show the file CosTransactions.idl

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g4Mgu8dN here it is!

Comment: In some systems, it's not possible to inherit from interfaces with forward declarations. (e.g., see http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/orbix/gen3/33/html/orbix33java_pguide/IDL.html). I am not sure this is true of Oracle's Java IDL compiler, but FYI that this could be related to the root cause.  Try taking out the forward declarations and trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a forward reference to interface Current, but the definition of this intreface is under the comments. Try to uncomment it.

Comment: i did but it didn't work, it says: org/omg/CORBA/Current is an undeclared type. and it refers to line 79 where it says: interface Current : CORBA::Current {

Comment: line 77:// Commented out to prevent IDL compiler from generating stubs etc. 
Did you write that?
I think, if you don't want to generate stubs(for remote call of the operations) for the interface, you shouldn't declare it in the idl file. As I see, you don't employ this interface anywhere in your idl file, so try to comment the forward reference to interface Current and the definition of this interface